# Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name - Session Factory in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao, sessionfactory

I am getting the below error while working with Hibernate. Could you please figure out what is causing this error.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to initialize group definition. 
 Group resource name [classpath*:beanRefFactory.xml], factory key [BeanFactory]; nested exception 
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
 'BeanFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/E:/Client/ 
 post/test.jar!/beanRefFactory.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception 
 is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class 
 [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
 with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of 
init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class 
net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method 
org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String; 
[Ljava/lang/String;)V
at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:389)
....
....
....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
... 155 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

I have defined the session factory bean as below in the applicationcontext.xml file and getting the database connection values from separate file database.properties.

```
<bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="JobDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
        
            <value>Entry.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>AccountMapping.hbm.xml</value>
            
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
         </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

please help me to solve this error and cause of this error too. any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The version of ASM that is expected by cglib is not the same as used at runtime. Looks like you might have messed up your dependencies or use incompatible versions.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that dependency versions were not compatible. I have updated the dependencies and now it is working fine.